# How to delete key from dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, del

When running this code

```
def mergeYaml(priorityYaml, defaultYaml):
  finalYaml = {}
  if isinstance(defaultYaml, dict):
    for dk, dv in defaultYaml.items():
      if dk in priorityYaml:
        finalYaml[dk] = mergeYaml(priorityYaml[dk], dv)
      else:
        finalYaml[dk] = dv
    for pk, pv in priorityYaml.items():
      if pk in finalYaml:
        if pv == None:
          finalYaml[pk].pop(pk, None) # Error is on this line
        else:
          finalYaml[pk] = mergeYaml(finalYaml[pk], pv)
      else:
        finalYaml[pk] = pv

  else:
    finalYaml = defaultYaml
  return finalYaml
```

Python throws the following error:

```
pop() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

If I change the pop to use named arguments

```
finalYaml[pk].pop(key=pk, default=None)
```

I get tis error:

```
pop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'
```

Not sure why Python thinks I'm passing in 3 arguements, but I suspect the first one is self. I just want to remove the key from the dict, and `del finalYaml[pk]` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `del dictionary[key]`

Comment: I just ran your code: it works fine for me. Both del and pop are valid ways to delete dictionary keys. I can only suspect that you somehow have dict redefined as a class, and what you are working with is not actually a true python dictionary.

Comment: As a means of additional insight, try printing pk  and checking what the type of `priorityYaml` is.